# Terminate a PowerShell proces

Tags: windows, powershell

I created a PowerShell proces based on the following code:

```
$server = "ServerName"
$process = [WMICLASS]"\\$server\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process" 
$result = $process.Create("C:\script.bat")
```

With these commands you can execute a batch file on a different server. Now this works perfectly but I am bit confused. Should I also terminate the proces?? And if so how could I terminate it?

Comment: The process will terminate by itself once the script returns. Could you not have tested this yourself?

Comment: I am not very familiar with PS scripting. So how could I test this myself? @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Log on to the `$server`, open task manager or process explorer and see if the new process quits by itself?

Comment: Whether or not you should terminate the process depends on what that script does/is supposed to do. If you need to terminate it you should be able to do so by running `Get-WmiObject -Computer $server -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId=$($result.ProcessId)" | ForEach-Object {$_.Terminate()}`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen AFAIK `Create()` is async and will return an object with the result of the process creation operation and the remote PID.